# Выбор ОС/системного решения для системы серверов управления видеомонтажа с NAS

Tags: linux, big-data

Интересует Linux сервер или другая производительная система + файловая система с подключенным к серверу i-Stor iS16S6S6 c [JBOD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBOD) обьемом на 116 *терабайт*, часть сервера используется для хранения и монтирования на 5 одновременно работающих монтажных станциях (MacOS Maverick + пакет Adobe)

Требуется максимальная скорость работы (выбор файловой системы) и Разграничение прав : монтажеры, редаторы, архивисты.  плюс какая-то защита от потерь/удалений.

Сейчас файловая система HFS+  через SAS сервер MacOS Xserver 10.6 - старенький уже

Хотелось бы увеличения скорости, надежности, возможности востановления.

Особенно интересует Linux, знаком с деривативами Debian(Ubuntu, Mint) и OpenSUSE

Какие архитектурные решения вы бы порекомендовали для такой задачи?

Comment: debian, большое количество линуксовых дистрибутивов, включая убунту, ответвляются от него.

Comment: Классический ответ - тот, который знает и любит Ваш близжайший линукс гуру.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask - ещё лучше прочитать сначала это. ИМХО, вопрос как раз соответствует тому, что описано в ссылке.

А если уж слишком интересно, то полностью поддерживаю @KoVadim.

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian/linuxMINT практически одно и то же,  особенно в серверной части. А серверного минта, думаю, вообще нет. . Выбирают обычно между debian (ака убунту)/redhat (ака centos)/suse/freebsd (ака не линукс)

Answer (score 2):

Берите Ubuntu. Достаточно широко распространена. А то возьмете OpenSUSE или LinuxMINT, а потом окажется, что на VPS хостинге Вам их не могут предоставить. Хотя и различия будут незначительными, но осадочек останется.